# Interior color gives error in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a runtime error, 1004 when I run the below code in vba

```
MsgBox Workbooks(SourceFile1).Worksheets(WS).Range(Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn), Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn)).Interior.Color
```

but don't get any error in the following code:

```
MsgBox Workbooks(DestinationFile).Sheets(1).Range(Cells(I, 14), Cells(I, 14)).Interior.Color
```

The SourceFile1 opens up as I coded it do so. Also ThisRow shows a value of 9 and ThisColumn shows as 11 in debug mode

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: What are the values of **ws** and **SourceFile1** and **I**

Comment: We'll need to see a bit more code to understand what `ws` `ThisRow` `ThisColumn` etc. are.

Comment: in debug mode they show the values as when I hover the mouse cursor above them:

WS="RETAIL"
SourceFile1="Master.xlsx"
ThisRow=9
ThisColumn=11
I renamed ThisRow and ThisColumn to TRow and TColumn but to no avail
When I hover the mouse over Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn) it shows a value from the workbook which ran the macro but not from the workbook SourceFile1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your variables are appropriate, your Cells calls are not properly qualified with a worksheet - you need:

```
With Workbooks(SourceFile1).Worksheets(WS)
MsgBox .Range(.Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn), .Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn)).Interior.Color
End With
```

or in this case, since you are looking at one cell only:

```
Msgbox Workbooks(SourceFile1).Worksheets(WS).Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn).Interior.Color
```

Comment: thanks this Msgbox Workbooks(SourceFile1).Worksheets(WS).Cells(ThisRow, ThisColumn).Interior.Color works!!!!